# Slow count postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-10

I have a table with 36M entries and I want to count some of these entries based on a index/foreign key.

this is my request :

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM batch_item 
WHERE batch_id = '38212ee5-84b4-4c08-99a7-7f30ac52f4bf'
```

`batch_id` is an indexed field. Why does this request takes 4 seconds?

**EDIT:**
I have 36 different batch_id in this table.
I created my table and indexes like this :

```
create table batch_item
(
  id               uuid         not null
    constraint batch_item_pkey
    primary key,
  batch_id         uuid
    constraint fk_8f7fcfe1f39ebe7a
    references batch
    on delete cascade,
  source_code      varchar(255) not null,
  target_code      varchar(255) default NULL :: character varying,
  status           varchar(255),
  description      varchar(255) not null,
  infos            json,
  target_code_tops json,
  added_on         timestamp(0) not null,
  updated_on       timestamp(0) not null,
  code_fake        varchar(255) default NULL :: character varying,
  stat_target_code varchar(255) default NULL :: character varying,
  stats_infos      json,
  processed        boolean      not null
);

create index idx_8f7fcfe1f39ebe7a
  on batch_item (batch_id);

create index idx_8f7fcfe17b00651c
  on batch_item (status);

create index batch_item_si_kcf_index
  on batch_item ((stats_infos ->> 'keycatFinder' :: text));

create index batch_item_tct_best_keycat_index
  on batch_item ((((target_code_tops ->> 'best' :: text) :: json) ->> 'keycat' :: text));

create index batch_item_tct_low_keycat_index
  on batch_item ((((target_code_tops ->> 'low' :: text) :: json) ->> 'keycat' :: text));

create index idx_8f7fcfe1ba0d2629
  on batch_item (target_code);
create index idx_8f7fcfe1fb269bae
  on batch_item (code_fake);
create index idx_8f7fcfe1769fb59b
  on batch_item (source_code);
create index idx_8f7fcfe16de44026
  on batch_item (description);
create index idx_8f7fcfe127fb1b8b
  on batch_item (processed);
create index idx_8f7fcfe127fb1b8bf39ebe7a
  on batch_item (processed, batch_id);
```

the result of `explain analyze`:

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=2974200.67..2974200.68 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=51735.494..51735.494 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Gather  (cost=2974200.46..2974200.67 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=51735.378..51738.653 rows=3 loops=1)
    Workers Planned: 2
    Workers Launched: 2
    ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=2973200.46..2973200.47 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=51690.519..51690.519 rows=1 loops=3)
          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on batch_item  (cost=0.00..2964145.93 rows=3621812 width=0) (actual time=3161.252..51381.176 rows=1929799 loops=3)
                Filter: (batch_id = '38212ee5-84b4-4c08-99a7-7f30ac52f4bf'::uuid)
                Rows Removed by Filter: 10187060
Planning time: 0.139 ms
Execution time: 51738.693 ms
```

Comment: Could you also share the `explain analyze` of this query? btw: 4 secs seem reasonable for a 36m table.

Comment: How many different `batch_id` are in the table? How many records maximal for a `batch_id`?

Comment: Postgres does not use the index on batch_id for some reason. It expects a lot more rows that it actually gets. Are the statistics up-to-date? Does `analyze batch_item` change the plan (to an index scan)?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `create index idx_8f7fcfe127fb1b8b
  on batch_item (processed);` can be removed as there is another index that has `processed` as the leading column

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i ran the `analyze batch_item` and now it doesn't use a "Parallel Seq Scan" but a `Parallel Index Only Scan using idx_8f7fcfe1f39ebe7a on batch_item` which is way more faster :-).
But does this means that i will have to run an `analyze batch_item` every time I add documents? Or is there a way to automate it? Do you have any documentation about this that could explain me how it works for pg side.

(thank you for the tip on the processed index)

Comment: No, you don't usually need to do that manually. This _should_ happen automatically, but if you e.g. do large batch updates, deletes or inserts, then it makes sense. Depending on how the table is used, it might be necessary to configure autovacuum to adjust to your environment. See e.g. here: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/11/04/autovacuum-not-the-enemy/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `COUNT()` in Postgres reads through all rows and gets very slow.

### Solution 1. Keep `COUNT()` results in standalone table.

**Step 1. Create table:**

```
CREATE TABLE batch_item_counts (
  batch_id uuid,
  "count" bigint default 0
);
```

This table will have only 36 rows - 1 row per 1 unique `batch_id`.

**Step 2. Init values** via such query:

```
INSERT INTO batch_item_counts
SELECT batch_id, COUNT(1)
FROM batch_item
GROUP BY batch_id;
```

**Step 3. Keep values actual** via trigger on main table `FOR INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE FOR EACH ROW` which do recount items. Note: the trigger must insert new row when new `batch_id` value was inserted to main table and delete existing row when existing `batch_id` value was completely removed from main table.

---

### Solution 2. Simpler, but approximate.

Use system statistics table or parser for results of `EXPLAIN query` to get *approximate* COUNT(). [Details here.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate)

---

Note: index on `batch_id` will have very small profit since main table values are often repeated - you have only 36 different values on 36M rows.

Comment: "*reads through all rows and gets very slow"* - not true if you supply a where condition that can be supported by an index.